# Identify this film about a couple who escape from the police down a waterfall

Tags: identify-this-movie

There's a girl in an all-girls school, or perhaps a convent. One night they have some kind  of dance, and get to dance with these men, who I seem to remember are convicts, seems a bit strange though. The girl meets and falls in love with one of the men, they then make out in some kind of church with lots of candles around them.

At one point in the film, the boy is running through a forest and sees the girl lying in a pond photographing herself, with all the photography gear.

They run away together and live in a hut on a mountain somewhere but the police eventually catch up with them. A police helicopter appears right next to their hut but they manage to escape somehow by (I think) jumping off a waterfall, and then going underwater through a tunnel.

I would say it's from the 80's or 90's.

Answer (score 8):

You are looking for the 1986 film, "[Fire With Fire](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091053/)".

The boy is from a prison camp, and she is from a Catholic school. She is floating in the lake recreating the painting Ophelia for a photography class, when he sees her during a training exercise. They eventually run away together, setting the scene for the pursuit later.

Comment: Dude, you're a legend. Been looking for years.